# How to create an Intent that launches Calendar app on Android?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm trying to add a button that launches the Calendar app on Android 13:

```
private fun openCalendar() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        data = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI
        setPackage("com.android.calendar")
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

But this throws the following Exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.calendar/... pkg=com.android.calendar }
```

How can I launch the calendar in an alternative way?

Comment: Can you define more what you mean by "launches the Calendar app"? `ACTION_VIEW` is to view some specific piece of content. Also, please bear in mind that not everybody has `com.android.calendar`, let alone wants to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
private fun openCalendar() {
    val intent = Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath("time").build()
    )
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

This will open the calendar installed on your Android 13 device